# Tree search function

Tags: tree-structure, tree-search

Any node can have any number of children. To search this tree i wrote something like this

```
function Search(key, nodes){

 for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {


        if (nodes[i].key == key) {
            return nodes[i];
        }



        if (nodes[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
            return this.Search(key, nodes[i].children);
        }


    }
```

which doesn't quite work...any input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only recursively search the first node that has children.

You should rewrite that last conditional to something like this:

```
if (nodes[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
    var node = this.Search(key, nodes[i].children);
    if(node != null)
        return node;
}
```

You also need to add a case for if the node is not found - for example, a `return null` at the very bottom of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a base case. What happens when you encounter a node that has no children and also is not the node you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If this is Javascript, `this` in your code `this.Search` is probably what's giving you the problem.  `this` means "the current Function object."  Try replacing `this.Search` with just `Search`.